# Is a "CFRelease" needed if I am using CGImageSourceCreateWithData from a (__bridge)?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-foundation

My question is very simple, I would like to know if the method **"CGImageSourceCreateWithData"** creates a new object copying the data I provide so that that I have to release it when I don't need it anymore, or if it just creates a reference to the data I already have so that if I release it I will lose this data (and possibly have bad access errors).

The issue is related to using (__bridge CFDataRef) as the source data. Which let's me use Core Foundation objects as toll-free in ARC mode.

Consider the following function (or method, not sure how it's called):

```
- (void)saveImageWithData:(NSData*)jpeg andDictionary:(NSDictionary*)dicRef andName:(NSString*)name
{
    [self setCapturedImageName:name];

    CGImageSourceRef  source ;

    // Notice here how I use __bridge
    source = CGImageSourceCreateWithData((__bridge CFDataRef)jpeg, NULL);

    CFStringRef UTI = CGImageSourceGetType(source); 

    NSMutableData *dest_data = [NSMutableData data];

    // And here I use it again
    CGImageDestinationRef destination = CGImageDestinationCreateWithData((__bridge CFMutableDataRef)dest_data,UTI,1,NULL);

    CGImageDestinationAddImageFromSource(destination,source,0, (__bridge CFDictionaryRef) dicRef);

    BOOL success = NO;
    success = CGImageDestinationFinalize(destination);

    if(!success) {
        NSLog(@"***Could not create data from image destination ***");
    }

    // This only saves to the disk
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; // Get documents folder
    NSString *dataPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"ARPictures"];

    NSError *error;
    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:dataPath])
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:dataPath withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:&error]; //Create folder

    NSString *fullPath = [dataPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.jpg", name]]; //add our image to the path

    [dest_data writeToFile:fullPath atomically:YES];


    self.img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:dest_data]; 
    self.capturedImageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithData:dest_data];

    //This is what im not sure if i should use
    CFRelease(destination);
    CFRelease(source);

}
```

My concern is about memory leaks or dealocating things I should not.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are doing it correctly. It does not actually matter whether these routines make copies or not. What matters is that you `CFRelease` what you "Create" (or "Copy"). Everything here looks correct. `__bridge` is appropriate when passing parameters because you're not actually transferring the object from CF to Cocoa or vice versa. You're just temporarily "bridging" (casting) it.

Comment: Oh i see, so basically what i create i should always release right? I was a bit confused because i wanted to optimize this code, and was considering the possibility of using the cocoa objects directly bridging them so that I dont have these extra 2 copies. Becase right now i have the Original data (the jpeg data that comes in), the source and the destination and even tho i release the last 2 the process seems to consume a lot of memory. Can this be done?
btw thanks for ur fast reply

Comment: You need to balance a CFRelease with any method that includes Create or Copy in the name. As for the rest, I'm not certain why you're using Core Graphics here. You can convert JPEG data into a UIImage with `imageWithData:`. Are you doing something more complex in there?

Comment: Yeah, I am modifying the metadata from the image by adding some extra information, so i thought that this was the only way to modify that data.

Comment: ok; yes, this is the way to do that. So when you say "seems to consume a lot of memory," how are you checking this? Remember, when you free memory, it doesn't immediately go back to the OS. You'll actually hold onto it in case you need it again, and the OS will only really take it back if it needs it. I recommend the Instruments Allocation tool for tracing memory usage. Activity Monitor can sometimes send you down the wrong path.

Comment: Its just that my program crashes haha so i thought it would be the memory cuz no error is displayed and it just exists, I will try the allocation tool, thanks.

Comment: If they're crashing with the CFRelease, but not without, you should verify that `destination` and `source` are not `NULL`. CFRelease() will crash if you pass it NULL.

Comment: I just want to understand this clearly... even with ARC, we still have to worry about doing CFRelease() and also other types of releases such as CGContextRelease(context); ?

Comment: Correct. ARC only handles ObjC objects. It doesn't know anything about Core Foundation objects.